# Transforming json into coo sparse matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to transform a JSON file of shape:

```
{"1": 
{"2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 1, "6": 0, "7": 1, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0, "11": 1, "12": 1, "13": 0, "14": 1, "15": 1, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "20": 0, "21": 0, "22": 0, "23": 0, "24": 0, "25": 0, "26": 0, "27": 0, "28": 0, "29": 0, "30": 0, "31": 1, "32": 0, "33": 0, "34": 1, "35": 0, "36": 0, "37": 0, "38": 0, "39": 0, "40": 0, "41": 0, "42": 0, "43": 0, "44": 0, "45": 0},
 "2": 
{"2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 1, "7": 0, "8": 1, "9": 1, "10": 1, "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 1, "14": 1, "15": 1, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 1, "19": 0, "20": 1, "21": 1, "22": 0, "23": 0, "24": 0, "25": 1, "26": 0, "27": 0, "28": 0, "29": 1, "30": 0, "31": 1, "32": 1, "33": 0, "34": 0, "35": 0, "36": 0, "37": 1, "38": 0, "39": 0, "40": 1, "41": 1, "42": 0, "43": 0, "44": 1, "45": 1}, 
"3": 
{"2": 1, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 1, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0, "11": 0, "12": 0, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 0, "17": 0, "18": 0, "19": 0, "20": 0, "21": 0, "22": 0, "23": 0, "24": 0, "25": 0, "26": 0, "27": 0, "28": 0, "29": 0, "30": 0, "31": 1, "32": 0, "33": 0, "34": 0, "35": 0, "36": 0, "37": 0, "38": 0, "39": 0, "40": 0, "41": 0, "42": 0, "43": 0, "44": 0, "45": 0}, 
"4": 
{"2": 1, "3": 1, "4": 1, "5": 1, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0, "11": 1, "12": 1, "13": 0, "14": 0, "15": 0, "16": 1, "17": 1, "18": 0, "19": 0, "20": 0, "21": 0, "22": 1, "23": 1, "24": 1, "25": 0, "26": 1, "27": 1, "28": 1, "29": 0, "30": 1, "31": 0, "32": 0, "33": 0, "34": 1, "35": 0, "36": 1, "37": 0, "38": 1, "39": 0, "40": 0, "41": 0, "42": 1, "43": 1, "44": 0, "45": 0}}
```

into a coo sparse matrix where you have a coordinate showing the first key, then the second key, and then the value, as shown below:

```
(1,2) 0
(1,3) 0
(1,4) 0
(1,5) 1
...
(4,44) 0
(4,45) 0
```

I have tried converting the JSON file into a pandas data frame which looks like this:

```
in  1   2   3   4
2   0   0   1   1
3   0   0   0   1
4   0   0   0   1
5   1   0   0   1
6   0   1   0   0
7   1   0   1   0
8   0   1   0   0
9   0   1   0   0
10  0   1   0   0
11  1   0   0   1
12  1   0   0   1
13  0   1   0   0
14  1   1   0   0
15  1   1   0   0
16  0   0   0   1
17  0   0   0   1
18  0   1   0   0
19  0   0   0   0
20  0   1   0   0
21  0   1   0   0
22  0   0   0   1
23  0   0   0   1
24  0   0   0   1
25  0   1   0   0
26  0   0   0   1
27  0   0   0   1
28  0   0   0   1
29  0   1   0   0
30  0   0   0   1
31  1   1   1   0
32  0   1   0   0
33  0   0   0   0
34  1   0   0   1
35  0   0   0   0
36  0   0   0   1
37  0   1   0   0
38  0   0   0   1
39  0   0   0   0
40  0   1   0   0
41  0   1   0   0
42  0   0   0   1
43  0   0   0   1
44  0   1   0   0
45  0   1   0   0
```

But I haven't been able to transform this into a sparse matrix and it this will eliminate any functionality when scaling up.

Comment: Just iterate through the dictionary layers, and create the standard `coo` inputs by list appends.  See the `coo` docs for details on those 3 inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copy-n-paste your `json` to an Ipython session I get a dictionary with 4 keys.

I can unpack it into a list with:

```
In [466]: alist = [] 
     ...: for k,v in adict.items(): 
     ...:     for k1,v1 in v.items(): 
     ...:         alist.append((int(k),int(k1),v1)) 
     ...:
```

And make an array:

```
In [467]: arr = np.array(alist)                                                                              
In [468]: arr.shape                                                                                          
Out[468]: (176, 3)
```

and use the 3 columns of the array as inputs the `sparse.coo_matrix`:

```
In [469]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((arr[:,2],(arr[:,0],arr[:,1])))                                              
In [470]: M                                                                                                  
Out[470]: 
<5x46 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 176 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [471]: M.A                                                                                                
Out[471]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0]])
```

A variation:

```
In [472]: rows, cols, data = [],[],[] 
     ...: for k,v in adict.items(): 
     ...:     for k1,v1 in v.items(): 
     ...:         rows.append(int(k)) 
     ...:         cols.append(int(k1)) 
     ...:         data.append(v1) 
     ...:                                                                                                    
In [473]: len(rows)                                                                                          
Out[473]: 176
In [474]: M = sparse.coo_matrix((data,(rows,cols)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the dictionary in a "*multiindex dataframe*" through dictionary comprehension. For example with:

```
pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, orient='index') for k,v in data.items()})
```

For the given sample data, this will thus yield a dataframe with 176 rows and 1 column:

```
>>> pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame.from_dict(v, orient='index') for k,v in data.items()})
      0
1 2   0
  3   0
  4   0
  5   1
  6   0
  7   1
  8   0
  9   0
  10  0
  11  1
  12  1
  13  0
  14  1
  15  1
  16  0
  17  0
  18  0
  19  0
  20  0
  21  0
  22  0
  23  0
  24  0
  25  0
  26  0
  27  0
  28  0
  29  0
  30  0
  31  1
...  ..
4 16  1
  17  1
  18  0
  19  0
  20  0
  21  0
  22  1
  23  1
  24  1
  25  0
  26  1
  27  1
  28  1
  29  0
  30  1
  31  0
  32  0
  33  0
  34  1
  35  0
  36  1
  37  0
  38  1
  39  0
  40  0
  41  0
  42  1
  43  1
  44  0
  45  0

[176 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is great! But it returns a DF. I am trying to return a coo sparse matrix instead.